# Error of estimation of $\frac{\cos (n)}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty{\frac{\cos (n)}{n}}$ coverges. And I want to find such $n$ that the error of estimation of this series is less than $\epsilon$. All I know about reminder of series is the theorem about error estimation of alternating series and one about reminder comparison with integral. But both of theorems can't be used here.

Comment: Perhaps it might help to know *how* you know the series converges. That proof should give insight into this estimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C_n=\sum_{k=0}^n{\cos(k)}$, we have
$$ \sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(k)}{k}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}{\frac{C_k-C_{k-1}}{k}}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}{\frac{C_k}{k}}-\sum_{k=n}^{+\infty}{\frac{C_k}{k+1}}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}{\frac{C_k}{k(k+1)}}-\frac{C_n}{n+1}$$
Moreover, $$C_n=\mathrm{Re}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n{e^{ik}}\right)=\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{1-e^{i(n+1)}}{1-e^i}\right)$$
Thus $|C_n|\leqslant\left|\frac{1-e^{i(n+1)}}{1-e^i}\right|\leqslant\frac{2}{|\sin(1/2)|}$ and
$$ \left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}{\frac{\cos(k)}{k}}\right|\leqslant\frac{2}{|\sin(1/2)|}\left(\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{k(k+1)}}+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=\frac{4}{|\sin(1/2)|(n+1)} $$
Thus if you want that $\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}{\frac{\cos(k)}{k}}\right|<\varepsilon $, you must take $n\geqslant\left\lfloor \frac{4}{\varepsilon|\sin(1/2)|}\right\rfloor$.

Comment: It is a little bit complicated for me, but thank you!

Comment: The main idea is in the first line, what is below is not very important, only operations and calculus.